# regex to find a word in a sentence

Tags: regex, groovy

I have a string like following:

`CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE some_temp_table_name`

or

`CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE some_temp_table_name something else`

with the regex I want to strip out whatever is in bold letters.

I have the following regex

```
([a-z].*[\s]*)
```

what should I change in the regex?

Comment: What language/framework are you using to execute this regular expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

> `([A-Z\s]+)[a-z_]+\s?([a-z\s]+)`

In Groovy you would do something like this:

```
String clean 
    = yourString.replaceAll("([A-Z\s]+)[a-z_]+\s?([a-z\s]+)", "$1$2");
```

Comment: thanks. that works. but not for first sentence where there is no space after the word I wish to fetch. will changing your answer to ([a-z_]+)\s be alright for that requirement?

Comment: My mistake - my initial answer was wrong.  Please see my update.

Comment: wow hmm your new regex selects the whole string. rather than just the word i wish for..

Comment: Yes it does match the whole string but the two capture groups capture the text you want to _keep_.  You need to replace with `\1\2` to remove the text in the middle you don't need.  If you let me know what language you are using I can help you with the code that will do the replacement.

Comment: The Groovy code doesn't work for me, complains about an "Unexpected char '\'".

Comment: should be: String clean 
    = yourString.replaceAll("([A-Z\s]+)[a-z_]+\s?([a-z\s]+)", '$1$2');
because in groovy strings the values are outputted this way: "${somvar}"

Answer (score 1):

Based on the 2 cases you provided, the following should work in Groovy:

```
def s1 = "CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE some_temp_table_name"
def s2 = "CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE some_temp_table_name something else"

def t1 = s1 =~ /CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE (\w+)/ 
def t2 = s2 =~ /CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE (\w+)/ 

assert "some_temp_table_name" == t1[0][1]
assert "some_temp_table_name" == t2[0][1]
```

Answer (score 0):

try? :

```
([a-zA-Z\s]+TABLE)\s\b[a-zA-Z_]+\b(.*)
```

Answer (score 0):

If my goal would be to extract lowcase parts I'd do the following in ruby:

```
'CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE some_temp_table_name '.gsub(/[A-Z]/,'').gsub(/[\s]{2,}/, ' ').strip
```